# Get a table row's first td ID and then map it

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a function where a user clicks a button which will list out all computer names that are "ready" rather than not ready.  Ready is either defined as the last column in the table or the tr with a class of "highlight_green".  I need to use map because I need to toss the computer names out to a DB.

```
<table>
   <th>Counter</th><th>Machine Name</th><th>Status</th>
   <tr class='highlight_green'><td>1</td><td class='mac_name'>Machine_A</td><td>Ready</td>
   <tr class='highlight_red'><td>2</td><td class='mac_name'>Machine_B</td><td>Not Ready</td>
   <tr class='highlight_red'><td>3</td><td class='mac_name'>Machine_C</td><td>Not Ready</td>
   <tr class='highlight_green'><td>4</td><td class='mac_name'>Machine_D</td><td>Ready</td>
</table>
```

So far I have this code and this is where I'm stuck because I've tried numerous ways and I can't figure out how to point it to the correct td to grab the computer name.

```
$('#mark_a4_upgrade').click(function () {

            var texts = $('tr.highlight_green').map(function () {

              alert('The following machines are ready go to: ' + texts.join(', '));
            });
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know

```js
$('#mark_a4_upgrade').click(function () {
console.log('The following machines are ready go to: ');
            var texts = $('tr.highlight_green td').filter(function() {
                return $(this).index() === 1;
            }).map((i, e) => {
              console.log($(e).text());
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
   <th>Counter</th><th>Machine Name</th><th>Status</th></tr>
   <tr class='highlight_green'><td>1</td><td class='mac_name'>Machine_A</td><td>Ready</td></tr>
   <tr class='highlight_red'><td>2</td><td class='mac_name'>Machine_B</td><td>Not Ready</td></tr>
   <tr class='highlight_red'><td>3</td><td class='mac_name'>Machine_C</td><td>Not Ready</td></tr>
   <tr class='highlight_green'><td>4</td><td class='mac_name'>Machine_D</td><td>Ready</td></tr>
</table>

<button id="mark_a4_upgrade"></button>
```

Comment: Works in your example, thank you, but when applied to my code I'm getting Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment on the    }).map((i, e) = > { line.

Comment: did you notice your code was missing lots of matching tags like `<tr>`s and so, you also had a `<th>` *floating around* with no `<tr>` enclosing it, check that and if that is not the problem, share more of the code that is causing the error

Comment: Source code is fine, can't really paste it because it's dynamically generated.  Not sure why it's generating that error yet but I'll play with it and accept your answer considering it works for the example.  Thank you!

Comment: @spas2k if you are working in FF, use the inspector (rgthclick -> Inspect Element) once you are there you click on any tag and press F2, you will be able to copy all generated html that way, still willing to help :)